# Codeigniter cannot extend controller

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, controller

I have created an `admin` controller that extends the `blog` controller (both are located in application/controller). However, when I tried to access the controller, it gives me an error that the `blog` controller was not found. If I put `require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/blog.php');` inside the `admin.php` file it works. But I'm just wondering if there's another possible way to extends the `blog` controller without having to use `require_once` inside the `admin.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CI user guide

> If you are extending the Controller
>   core class, then be sure to extend
>   your new class in your application
>   controller's constructors.
>
> ```
> class Welcome extends MY_Controller {
>
>     function __construct()
>     {
>         parent::__construct();
>     }
>
>     function index()
>     {
>         $this->load->view('welcome_message');
>     }
> ```
>
> }

That means your `Blog` controller must extends `CI_Controller`

Example:

```
class MY_Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function hello() {
        $data = 'something';
    }
}

class Admin extends MY_Blog {

    function do_something() {}
}
```

[Userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)